# nodejs - wait for tcp prestart script

Tags: node.js, tcp

Looking for solid way to verify a dependent service is online and ready before starting a node test script. The script just connects to an oracle database and executes a simple query.

In my case, an npm prestart script that checks and waits (with timeout) for a tcp listener could be appropriate, but so would a pattern more appropriate for microservices. My question is twofold, im looking for the pattern to follow, and I'm is not exactly clear to me how to do this with net (if net is the right tool).

Comment: Are we talking about microservices here? Because with microservices your services should be able to start anyway. Even if possible dependency services are offline.. They need to be able to handle the possible outage of services.

Comment: that is an excellent point an while intending to be generic, i am confusing issues. my app is actually just a test of a preconfigured docker service that has the node-oracle db client. prestart would be ok. so would another pattern.